# Unable to install most major packages; Unmet dependencies and cannot be fixed

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, and it seems that most major packages I attempt to install (among them being Skype, Steam/Steam-Launcher, WINE, etc.), give an "unmet dependencies" error and refuse to install.

I have looked at several other questions of a similar description (many duplicates) but none of the solutions worked and I have not yet found someone with this specific issue.

Installing Skype:

```
stere0123@stere0123-THINKPAD-U14:~$ sudo apt-get install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
stere0123@stere0123-THINKPAD-U14:~$
```

I get similar errors with some other packages I've tried as well.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as this problem is currently crippling this system!

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Perhaps because you did not mention what you tried to resolve the problem and this is a FAQ. At any rate, I upvoted the question to offset the downvote a tad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change download server as suggested above:

Open your source.list using your favorite text editor, ie

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
locate http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu and replace it with http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt-get -f install

It will solve you'r problem.

[see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110656/ffmpeg-unmet-dependencies)
and [thia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177468/unmet-dependencies-in-ubuntu-12-04) there are lot of question on this topic.

Comment: I already tried this several times and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-updates-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error once see this link.

Comment: and follow the steps.